# Constructing a specific measure from a given measure such that its Rdon Nikodym derivative takes specific values

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, radon-nikodym

Take a measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \tau, P)$, with $P$ being a probability measure, and $\tau$ being a topology on $\Omega$.
I would like to construct a measure $Q$ such that $Q$ is equivalent to $P$, for its RN derivative exists, and that the RN derivative $f$ is as close as possible to $P$ itself as possible.
A first idea (from the RN derivatives definition) would be to define $Q$ via a neighbourhood filter $N_\omega \subset \tau$ of a point $\omega \in \Omega$ (similar to how one defines well defined conditional probability). Thus I would write down the expression

$Q(E) := \int\limits_E \lim\limits_{\{\omega\} \subset N_\omega} P(N_\omega) \; dP(\omega) $

Is this a sensible approach ? Is there any neat way of evaluating this expression ? Or is there an alternative approach which is more sensible ?

Thanks a lot in advance ! :)

Comment: What do you mean by "$Q$ is equivalent to $P$"?

Comment: What I mean is that I want that both $Q$ to be absolutely continuous w.r.t. $P$ as well as vice versa, that is, basically, their kernels are the same and the Radon Nikodyn derivative $f = \frac{dP}{dQ}$ as well as $f^{-1} = \frac{dQ}{dP}$ exist

Comment: $P$ is a probability measure. Its value is defined for sets in $\mathcal{A}$. It is **not** defined on neighbourhood filter $N_\omega \subset \tau$ of a point $\omega \in \Omega$. So there is no meaning to $P(N_\omega)$.

Comment: You say that you would like "that the RN derivative [of $Q$] $f$ is as close as possible to $P$ itself as possible". The RN derivative $f$ is a measurable function and $P$ is a probability measure. In which sense do you mean them to be "close"?

Comment: If all you want is another probability measure $Q$ such that $Q\ll P$ and $P\ll Q$. Just take any $\mathcal{A}$-measurable function $f: \Omega \rightarrow [0,+\infty)$ such that $f>0$ $a.e.[P]$ and $\int_\Omega f dP=1$. Define, for all $E\in \mathcal{A}$, $$Q(E)=\int_E f dP$$. It folows immediately that $Q$ is a probability measure,  $Q\ll P$ and $P\ll Q$, $\frac{dQ}{dP}=f$ and $\frac{dP}{dQ}=\frac{1}{f}$.

Comment: Hey Ramiro, thanks a lot for your comments! Of course, in the sense that $\tau$ has no relation with $\mathcal{A}$, $P$ is not defined on $N_\omega$ per se, you're absolutely right. So that doesn't make sense. One could, however, construct a net of sets $N_\omega \subset \mathcal{A}$ ordered by set inclusion to make sure they're all measurable.
Yes I absolutely see that from the definition of the RN derivative, the construction of such a $Q$ by any $\mathcal{A}$-measurable function is possible, but I would like to (ideally) find a measure $Q$ s.t. $f = g(P)$ where g is close to the identity

Comment: Even if all the sets in $N_\omega$ are in $ \mathcal{A}$, $P$ is defined on sets in $ \mathcal{A}$, not sets of sets in $ \mathcal{A}$.  So $P(N_\omega)$ is not defined. 
What do you want to mean by $P(N_\omega)$?

Comment: Thank you a lot or your time and efforts, @Ramiro ! :)
What I had in mind when writing $P(N_\omega)$ was that, like $N_\omega \subset \tau$ can be thought of as a sequence when ordered by set inclusion with limit $\{\omega\}$, I meant to generate a sequence $P_i = P(N_\omega^i)$ applying $P$ to the $i$-th set in the net $N_\omega \subset \mathcal{A}$ and then take its downward limit. That was the basic idea, however, I strongly suspect the $P_i$ to converge to 0 for non-atomic measures, which is quite unsatisfying, telling me the approach is not correct for my purpose.

Comment: Since $P$ is a probability (finite measure), $P(N_\omega^i)$ will always converge to $P(\bigcap_i N_\omega^i)$. Since $\{N_\omega^i\}$ is taken such that the sequence converge to $\{\omega\}$,  we will have that 
$$\lim_i P(N_\omega^i) = P\left (\bigcap_i N_\omega^i \right) = P(\{\omega\})$$ 
So your notation "$P(N_\omega)$" just means $P(\{\omega\})$.

Comment: Yes, this was what I suspected in my last comment, too, that for non atomic measures we'll simply get $P_i \to P(\{\omega\}) = 0$, which is exactly what I do not want to happen, unfortunately.